# .Net RIA Services: Multiple loads to one callback

Tags: .net, wcf-ria-services

I have found that it's quite often the case I have multiple queries/entities that I want to load in RIA Services that are all related, and a single callback that processes the data once the loads have all been completed. However, I don't see a clean, easy way to do this with RIA Services without adding my own boilerplate code to either count callbacks (as in if I have three loads, then in the callback have a class variable that increments and returns if still < 3), or by chaining the loads, which wastes time since the load calls could be concurrent.

I'm starting to think my best option is to make a separate, reusable little class called "LoadGroup" that takes in multiple load queries and a callback function, and only invokes the callback once all the loads have completed. My question is: am I re-inventing the wheel here? Is there functionality of RIA Services that already basically does this (or a design pattern better than the one I'm suggesting)? Or should I go ahead with my plan of writing my own little class?

Thanks,

-Robert

Comment: I'm surprised this question isn't really popular...

Answer (score 1):

There is no chaining mechanism so your option to setup a master handler is the normal route.  One other way to pull this off would be to simply expose a Model through Invoke which encapsulates all of the calls into a single result so that three calls to:

```
IQueryable<SomeType1> GetSomeType1()
{
}

IQueryable<SomeType2> GetSomeType2()
{
}

IQueryable<SomeType2> GetSomeType2()
{
}
```

Can be returned as (mock class)

```
public class SomeModel()
{
   public List<SomeType1> FirstCall()
   public List<SomeType2> SecondCall()
   public List<SomeType3> ThirdCall()
}
```

Exposed as an Invoke:

```
[Invoke]
    public SomeModel GetMultiple( IQueryable<SomeType1> first, IQueryable<SomeType2> second, IQueryable<SomeType3> third )
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting approach. Thanks for the idea! And when I said "chaining," I meant using lambdas as callbacks so that the first load's callback makes the call to the second load, and the second load's callback makees the call to the third load, ... , and then the last load has the real callback. But obviously this removes all concurrency and slows things down, so it's not ideal by any means.

Comment: I thought you meant to bundle up the calls into a single orchestrating function that fails or succeeds as a group.  This model approach us a little more ideal.  I do not use MVVM in my Silverlight projects, but this is essentially just taking that approach of exposing out a View Model built to purpose that comes back in a single call.